# exc_bad_access with UIImagePickerController and UIPopoverController

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, exc-bad-access, uipopovercontroller, nsautoreleasepool

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS right after calling this piece of code in my app (Ipad)

I get almost nothing from XCode for debugging, XCode points me that line of code:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

I guess an object has been autoreleased too early but why and how to fix this?

```
NSLog(@"OpenPhotoDialog");
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = srcType;

UIDevice* thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker] ;
popover.delegate = self;

[popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually EXC_BAD_ACCESS Will Come  Sending Object To the Deallocated Blocks.

if you set The Argument in Executables

NSZombieEnabled YES

Then you Can Know Which Object is De allocating Which is So longer Used.

cheers

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie with xcode and i encountered the same problem, where will i set the nszombieEnabled YES?